# Non-team variants for four or more players in Mille Bornes?

Tags: house-rules, mille-bornes

Has anyone come across variant rules for Mille Bornes where the players don't play on teams?  I've seen rules for 2 player, 3 player, 2 vs 2 and 3 vs 3, but nothing for four or more solo players.

For whatever reason, sometimes we'll have a group of four or more who feels like playing, but all playing solo.  The problem is, someone always ends up running out of fuel or getting a flat tire, and then never seeing a Petrol or Repair card for the rest of the game.  They end up just sitting there, which is pretty non-entertaining.

It is quite possible that the deck just isn't suitable for more than three players, and playing with two decks is the only way to have more than three solo players, but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened in my gaming group as well, we fixed it simply by having a remedy 'timer' which is once you've been stuck for 3 turns, any GO card would suffice to move again.  Likewise, if stopped for three turns, you could simply play mileage cards.

The other variant we tried, which you might like is that remedy cards (and go cards) were played into a face-up draw stack, and instead of drawing normally, you could draw from any used card in the stack, so once someone had fixed their flat tire, anyone could spend the turn to draw the remedy the second time.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks!  I had considered something like a timer, so that's good to have that reinforced.

Answer (score 0):

We play 5 and 6 player Mille Bornes without teams.  Our solution was to buy another deck of Mille Bornes cards and use those and play as you usually would.  You now have 220 cards instead of 110 cards.  We play five games.  1000 miles per game.  But we also stipulate that you must get exactly 1000 miles.  For example.  If you are at 975 miles you would need a 25 mile card to win.  Also, you must shout out Mille Bornes when you reach 1000 miles.  Hope this helps.  --- Mike

Comment: Did you play that one person can play 2 of the specials (puncture proof, ace, etc.) and the second one is just redundant?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem tonight with 5 players and began developing a variant that seemed to have some promise:
A player is given the option of offering an exchange of one of his cards for a desired card.
For example, if a player is stuck and really needs a spare tire card, he may announce that he is willing to offer to trade his    "extra tank" card (or whatever card he thinks might entice a trade) for a"spare tire" card. Any other player wishing to complete the proffered trade indicates as such and trade is made. The trade completes the players turn. If no one is willing or able to make the trade, the player's turn is forfeit.
We only played a couple of hands this way as it was getting late, but, as I said, I think it solves the basic problem of everyone being stuck, and makes for interesting game play.
I'd love to hear if it works for others and is further developed.